# Clicking on icons in the toolbar in my Kotlin project

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When I add the `R.id.action_latest` line to the code, no click event occurs on the screen, when I remove this code, the application returns to its previous state.

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu)
        return true
    }
    
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        
        return when (item.itemId) {
           
            R.id.action_more -> {
                showCustomDialog()
                true
            }
            R.id.action_latest -> {
                val fragment = LatestNewsFragment()
                val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                transaction.addToBackStack(null)
                transaction.commit()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

```xml
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F2F2F2">
    
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
    
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="InsMate"
                app:menu="@menu/toolbar_menu"
                android:background="#F2F2F2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

I want to make a page transition when I click on the icon in the `R.id.action_latest` row,
but I tried all the methods I know and they were not successful.

Comment: Can you please post the menu xml code?

Comment: I edited and added my question